# How to debug mapbox crash

Tags: android-ndk, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, ndk-stack

I have a redundant crash with mapbox library `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.1.1`

On the logcat I got this stack:

```
pid: 4960, tid: 4960, name: [...]  >>> [...] <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
r0 00000000  r1 6b9faf17  r2 0000010f  r3 00000001
r4 00000000  r5 b4d96a80  r6 00000003  r7 bef0db50
r8 bef0dae0  r9 b4db6500  sl bef0dbb0  fp b4db6500
ip b4cfc94c  sp bef0da88  lr b499dc29  pc 9fdc9ebc  cpsr 60060030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00095ebc  /data/app/[...]/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so
    #01 pc 00097545  /data/app/[...]/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so
    #02 pc 00097587  /data/app/[...]/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so
    #03 pc 000eaa29  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
    #04 pc 000e6331  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
    #05 pc 004028a5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+188)
    #06 pc 007fccdc  [stack]`
```

And trying to get a clear line number for `libmapbox-gl.so` with `ndk-stack`, I only got that:

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0.1/M4B30Z/3437181:user/release-keys'
pid: 4960, tid: 4960, name: [...]  >>> [...] <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
Stack frame #00 pc 00095ebc  /data/app/[...]/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #01 pc 00097545  /data/app/[...]/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #02 pc 00097587  /data/app/[...]/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #03 pc 000eaa29  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
Stack frame #04 pc 000e6331  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
Stack frame #05 pc 004028a5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+188)
Stack frame #06 pc 007fccdc  [stack]
```

Here is my `ndk-stack` command: `$ANDROID_LIB_PATH/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/servertest/release/0/lib/x86_64/ -dump logcat.txt`

How to get the line number where the crash happened?